# alternating row colors in a QComboBox in mac and linux

Tags: c++, qt4

I want to alternate the colors of a QComboBox. In Windows I have no problem using the view().setAlternatingRowColors(true) function. In Linux and Mac it looks like impossible. I tried also using style sheet (see following code) but I had the same kind of results (all rows with the same background color). Can you explain me what is my error?

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QAbstractItemView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setStyleSheet("QComboBox QAbstractItemView{qproperty-alternatingRowColors: true;alternate-background-color: blue;background: red;}");
    QComboBox b;
    b.addItem("MM_NONE");
    b.addItem("MM_VERT");
    b.addItem("MM_FACE");
    b.addItem("MM_EDGE");
    bool tt = false;
    tt = b.view()->alternatingRowColors();
    b.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At least on my box it appears that `QPalette::Base` and `QPalette::AlternateBase` are the same color :) Changing `QPalette::AlternateBase` to some other color makes this code work fine:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QAbstractItemView>
#include <QPalette>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QComboBox b;
    b.view()->setAlternatingRowColors(true);

    QPalette p = b.palette();
    p.setColor(QPalette::AlternateBase, Qt::red);
    b.setPalette(p);

    b.addItem("MM_NONE");
    b.addItem("MM_VERT");
    b.addItem("MM_FACE");
    b.addItem("MM_EDGE");
    b.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I tried it before and I retried it now with your own code (can always happen to make a stupid mistake) but unfortunately with my Ubuntu 11.10 and my Mac OsX 10.6.8 I have not the result I was waiting for. In windows it works perfectly but not in Linux and Mac. I have to write a multiplatform  code.

Comment: Also, your stylesheet solution worked fine on my Gentoo Linux... I'm using Qt 4.7.3

Comment: That said, it doesn't work on my Mac either :) But personally I haven't seen alternating colors of combo box rows on Mac.